# Operator with both arguments and limits

Tags: macros, math-operators

I'd like to define a command `\E` that can be used precisely as follows: it should translate

```
\E{f(x)}
\E_x{f(x)}
```

into

```
\mathbb{E}(f(x))
\mathbb{E}_x(f(x))
```

respectively. Specifically, the goal is to render them as

[image: screenshot]

respectively.

But notice that `_x` neither has the syntax of an optional nor of a mandatory argument.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: ...so your usage could be `\E{f(x)}` *or* `\E_x{f(x)}`?

Comment: Why to use `_x`?

Comment: @Werner: Yes, thanks for clarifying. Also, I just noticed I had a typo in the translated result, it's fixed now.

Comment: @Sigur: Because it's a subscript, so it makes the most sense. I realize I can do `[x]` which is the next-best alternative I can think of, but at least for learning I'd like to know if this is possible.

Comment: Well, just define `\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}` and type `\E(f(x))` or `\E_{x}(f(x))`; there's no advantage in having braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: @egreg: There's an advantage though, it means I can do `\left(` instead of `(` in the definition of `\E`, for example. Or whatever else I might want to do. Regardless, my question isn't about the advantage, it's about whether such a thing is possible. And lol, ok I'll change that, thanks.

Comment: @Mehrdad, egreg said that `{}` is just to group. Maybe what you wish is `\{\}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, by coupling this with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`.

### New answer (January 2021)

This also allows upper limits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\NewDocumentCommand{\E}{e{^_}}{%
  \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{^{#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
  \parens
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}{(}{)}

\begin{document}

$\E{f(x)}$

$\E[\big]{f(x)}$

$\E[\Bigg]{f(x)}$

$\E*{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\E_x{f(x)}$

$\E_x[\big]{f(x)}$

$\E_x[\Bigg]{f(x)}$

$\E_x*{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\E^x{f(x)}$ $\E_x^y[\big]{f(x)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If only lower limits are needed, one can simplify the definition into

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\E}{e{_}}{%
  \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}%
  \parens
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}{(}{)}
```

### Old answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}\@ifnextchar_{\m@Es}{\m@Epd}}
\newcommand{\m@Es}[2]{_{#2}\m@Epd}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\m@Epd}{(}{)}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\E{f(x)}$

$\E[\big]{f(x)}$

$\E[\Bigg]{f(x)}$

$\E*{\dfrac{1}{2}}$

$\E_x{f(x)}$

$\E_x[\big]{f(x)}$

$\E_x[\Bigg]{f(x)}$

$\E_x*{\dfrac{1}{2}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please, could you explain why the command `\m@Es` has 2 arguments if it uses only `#2`? Where is `#1`? I'm confused.

Comment: @Sigur Argument `#1` is the underscore `_` that we need to get rid of.

Comment: Is it also possible to translate just `\E` to `\mathbb{E}` (no parentheses)?

Comment: @user7802048 I'm not sure what you mean. Looking ahead for a `{` and decide what to do is not a good interface.